# Possible to provide a "resolved" StreamProvider to child widgets via nested ProviderScope?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to inject a "resolved" Riverpod StreamProvider object into the tree below to remove some unnecessary async calls. If my interpretation of the docs is correct, a nested ProviderScope should help with this but I am getting a runtime exception.

My use case: I need to access a user-specific *specs* object high in the widget tree. Some of the data from that object is required all over the remainder of the app, including as a parameter for any DB operation. The specs object comes from firebase and is retrieved async with a StreamProvider.

Once execution is inside the HomePage widget I *know* the specs object must be loaded and valid so I don't want to fetch it again as a Stream Provider that needs to handle load and error cases. This is especially true where the specs provider is input to other combined providers as the additional load and error cases add lots of unnecessary complexity.

```
// Called at the root of the tree to retieve some firestore object
final specsStreamProvider = StreamProvider<Specs?>((ref) {
  return ref.read(baseDatabaseProvider).currentSpecs();
});

// Called further down to provide the object that was retrieved
final specsProvider = Provider<Specs>((ref) {
  throw UnimplementedError('should have been overwritten');
});

// An example of how content will be retrieved from firestore at HomePage widget and below.
// Having to use specsStreamProvider here quickly turns into a mess.
final recordStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<Record>>((ref) {
  final specs = ref.read<Specs>(specsProvider);
  final database = ref.read(contentDatabaseProvider(specs.current!));
  return database.recordsStream();
});

class SetupWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const SetupWidget({Key? key, required this.setupBuilder, required this.homeBuilder}) : super(key: key);
  final WidgetBuilder setupBuilder;
  final WidgetBuilder homeBuilder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final specsAsyncValue = watch(specsStreamProvider);
    return specsAsyncValue.when(
      data: (specs) => _data(context, specs),
      loading: () => const Scaffold(/.../),
      error: (e, __) => Scaffold(/.../),
      ));
  }

  Widget _data(BuildContext context, Specs? specs) {
    if (specs != null) {
      return ProviderScope(
        // The plan here is to introduce the resolved specs into the tree below
        overrides: [specsProvider.overrideWithValue(specs)],
        child: homeBuilder(context),
      );
    }
    return setupBuilder(context);
  }
}
```

According to the Riverpod API a nested ProviderScope is a valid tool to overwrite providers for part of the widget tree. Unfortunately, in my case I get a runtime error 'Unsupported operation: Cannot override providers on a non-root ProviderContainer/ProviderScope'

I also tried to make specsProvider a ScopedProvider but then the combined recordStreamProvider doesn't compile. ('error: The argument type 'ScopedProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'RootProvider<Object?, Specs>'.'

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I figured it out. I made specsProvider a ScopedProvider set in the parent and changed recordStreamProvider (the one that is called in the children only) to not depend on the scoped provider directly.

However, I would still love to hear from one of the Riverpod experts if what I am doing here is acceptable and no anti-pattern.

Parent setting scoped provider:

```
final specsStreamProvider = StreamProvider<Specs?>((ref) {
  return ref.read(baseDatabaseProvider).currentSpecs();
});

// Called further down to provide the object that was retrieved
// This MUST be a ScopedProvider
final specsProvider = ScopedProvider<Specs>((ref) {
  throw UnimplementedError('should have been overwritten');
});

class SetupWidget extends ConsumerWidget {/* as before */}
```

Children consuming scoped provider

```
// no dependency on specsProvider here
final recordStreamProvider = StreamProvider.family.autoDispose<List<Record>, String>((ref, storeId) {
  final database = ref.read(contentDatabaseProvider(storeId));
  return database.recordsStream();
});

class HomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final specs = watch(specsProvider);
    final recordsAsyncValue = watch(recordsStreamProvider(specs.storeId!));

    return recordsAsyncValue.when(
      data: (records) => /* build a list */
      loading: () => /* show a progress indicator */,
      error: (e, __) => /* show an alert dialog */,
      ));
  }
}
```